# Rewrite Dynamic URL In PHP Using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-routing

I wanted to rewrite url in following pattern

My current url is:

xyz.com/news_details.php?id=120&title=hello-world

and I want the url as is:
xyz.com/hello-world

also I wanted to fetch the values of `id` on this page like:
`$id = $_REQUEST['id'];`

please help

I did use the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /news_details.php\?id=([^&\s]) [NC]  
RewriteRule ^ /%2\.html? [NC,R,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^-])\.html$ /news_details.php?id=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: Does that not just loop forever and cause a 508 error?

Comment: @CD001: what can be done

Comment: No you cannot show `xyz.com/hello-world` URL to clients and still get `id` parameter from request. You will have to query a database to get the `id` otherwise have your URL as `xyz.com/120/hello-world`

Comment: Well the URL you want to use is `xyz.com/hello-world` which doesn't contain `id=120` anywhere. What many frameworks/applications do is store the request URL and the *real* URL in the database and use a routing script to fetch the desired resource.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)$ /news_details.php?title=$1&id=$2
```

To achieve links like `http://example.net/hello-world/120`.

The `^/(.*)/(.*)$` part tells apache the pattern that it will follow. The second part (`news_details.php?title=$1&id=$2`) gives apache the real link that it will apply the pattern on.

You can't exactly hide arguments from the user, because you need a way to get the id that you want to have as the `id` argument. So that's the only possible way to do that.

You can read more about it [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: can you please explain me in detail that how to use this